# Run bash script curled from the web

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script that should be installable from the web. It should take inputs from the user when run. 
Below is how I did it but it directly terminates the application without prompting the user to input information.

```
curl www.test.com/script.sh | bash
```

I read somewhere that stdin is piped to bash that's why it's not prompting anything.

Any help would be great.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
bash <(curl www.test.com/script.sh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bash -c '`curl www.test.com/script.sh`'
```

Although this will have problems if the script has single quotes in it.

Failing that, do it in two steps:

```
curl -o /tmp/script.sh www.test.com/script.sh 
bash /tmp/script.sh
```

You can save the script anywhere you like, and for better security etc you might want to use `tmpfile` or something, but running a script straight off the net doesn't sound like high security anyway.

Comment: ``bash '`curl www.test.com/script.sh`'`` would not work even if there are no single quotes in it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the `-c` flag.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 bash -c "$(curl -s www.test.com/script.sh)"
```

From the bash manpage,

```
  -c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  
            If there are arguments after the string, they are
            assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

Comment: This will only work for scripts that are shorter than the maximum allowable command line for your system. POSIX only guarantees that this number is bigger than 4096, so this isn't portable if your script is longer.